# SQL Server Stored Procedure for Inserting or updating database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures and trying to learn things. I have a database table which looks likes this,

```
 Acc   | Room |  ID | Name |  Email | Status |  Date  | Number 
=======+======+=====+======+========+========+========+========
(null) |  101 | 001 |  ABC | (null) |   EMP  | (null) | (null) 
(null) |  102 | 002 |  DEF | (null) |   TMP  | (null) | (null)
```

I am creating a stored procedure to insert or update the data in the database depending on the ID. Not all the records has data to be inserted or updated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdate]
    @room char(35),
    @id char(12),
    @name varchar(64),
    @status varchar(50),
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT null FROM emp WHERE ID = @id)
    BEGIN
       UPDATE emp 
       SET Room = @room, ID = @id, Name = @name, Status = @status
       WHERE ID = @id
    END

    INSERT INTO emp (Room, ID, Name, Status)
    VALUES(@room, @id, @name, @status);
END
```

Not sure if this is correct, will this create the other records with null.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Looks like the latter; please don't tag with MySQL unless you're actually using that platform. "mysql" doesn't mean "my SQL code"...

Comment: A much better pattern (less prone to deadlocks) is `UPDATE ... WHERE ID = @id; IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 INSERT ...;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand how can I declare the @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: You don't need to declare `@@ROWCOUNT` - [it's a built-in function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) that returns the number of rows affected by the immediately previous statement.

Comment: @AaronBertrand @@ROWCOUNT will help if many rows of data are coming in for insert or update.

Comment: It will also help you tell whether your update affected 1 row (in which case your update is already done) or 0 rows (in which case you need to insert).

Comment: @AaronBertrand what happens if I have many records at a time.

Comment: Then your where clause won't be `WHERE ID = @id` now, will it? If it is, then your column has a terrible name. Well, it has a terrible name already, since it isn't specific, but really that should affect one row. If you're trying to insert or update multiple rows, then your stored procedure won't look like that at all, since all of those parameters are designed to affect exactly one row. Look into table-valued parameters where you can do `UPDATE` with a self-join and then `INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS`. This is serious scope creep.

Comment: @AaronBertrand so how can this be approached??

Answer (score -1):

First check if the Id exist. If it does not exist then its an insert else an update.

The body of stored proc can be:

```
BEGIN

declare @v_count int

select @v_count = count(ID) from emp
where ID = @id

if (@v_count = 0)
insert into emp (Room, ID, Name, Status)
values (@room, @id, @name, @status)

else
update emp
set Room = @room, Name = @name, Status = @status
where ID = @id

END
```

Comment: This approach performs an unnecessary additional access to the table, and makes the code more prone to deadlocks.

Comment: unnecessary additional access? in case of `insert` the access is 2 times; in case of `update` the access is 2 times. Its consistent. In which case the access is unnecessary additional?

Comment: No, if you just `UPDATE` first and `@@ROWCOUNT` > 0, then it's only one access.